# JavaScript audio object stopping in the middle of playing

Tags: javascript, audio

In a project I'm working on, I have a JS file that **should** play a piece of music, and when that piece is done playing, the next one takes its place.

```
var soundtrack = {
 0: new Audio("./music/piece1.ogg"),
 2: new Audio("./music/piece2.ogg"),
 1: new Audio("./music/piece3.ogg"),
 3: new Audio("./music/piece4.ogg")
}
var currentTrack = 0;
function startMusic(){
 soundtrack[currentTrack].play();
 soundtrack[currentTrack].addEventListener("ended", function(){ nextSong()});
}
function nextSong(){
 currentTrack += 1;
 if(currentTrack == 4){
     currentTrack = 0;
 }
 soundtrack[currentTrack].play();
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function() { startMusic(); }, 15500);
});
```

My use of the object "soundtrack" may be unconventional, but there was a bug using an array so I tried this and it worked.

The first piece plays through fine, and the next one starts up fine. About maybe 10 seconds in, the playing just stops.

Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Note: I am aware not all pieces will play after one other, I'm waiting until this issue is fixed before continuing.

Comment: what if you place the second piece in place of the first one?

Comment: @Kaiido Well, as you can see the numbers are already out of order... This is because I tried swapping the second piece with the third, this changed nothing, so I don't think it has to do with order

Comment: I wasn't concerned about the order but about the files. So you've got the same behavior on different files right ? Always at the same interval? Are you sure you don't have an other script interferring with it ?

Comment: Yes the same behavior happens on different files... I don't think I have another script interfering, since no script have yet been set to run after this one does.